# Local storage in boilerplate.js

Tags: html, boilerplatejs

How to support local storage in boilerplate.js?
The idea is to use jquery dform with localstorage and render it in a view there by the form view is extremely fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it normally as a dependency inside one of your modules. The module sampleModule2 shows a Backbone Todo example persisting into local storage using a simple localstorage.js

From what I can see of boilerplate.js it gives you the freedom to do whatever you want in each module. You could presumably elevate a requirejs dependency on localstorage.js up higher in the contexts if you wanted a more consistent access to localstorage across modules.